# Adding accordion-section to custom post type edit screen

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I'm trying to add accordion-style meta boxes to the edit screen of a custom post type on the right hand side beneath the "Publish" meta box.

Actually I'm kind of trying to replicate the Menu -> Appearance accordion, displaying it in the mentioned location.

I've been experimenting with the do_accordion_sections() function:

```
function add_accordion_section_meta_boxes() {
 do_accordion_sections( null, 'side', null );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_accordion_section_meta_boxes' );
```

It's sort of working, but the accordion is being displayed on top of the screen.

Is there any hook that will allow me to display the accordion in the desired location, or perhaps any function etc. that will allow for accordion-style meta boxes?

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to recreate the panels in the block editor sidebar but in the classic editor? `do_accordion_sections` needs more information than `null`/`side`/`null`, those `null` values need to be actual values. The function doesn't add accordions, it displays an accordion right there and then, like `echo`, it's not a registration function. That's why it displays at the top, because it displays when `add_meta_boxes` happens which is before the rest of the page is shown.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm trying to achieve. Looking at the function I think I can use null for testing purposes. I was suspecting the accordion would display on top of the screen because of the hook running in this location. That's why I was wondering if there was a hook that I could use instead of "add_meta_boxes".

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the block editor?

Comment: Do you mean the Gutenberg block editor? I'm trying to create metaboxes for different post types (post, page, etc) that contain lists with checkboxes and titles for every existing post from the respective post type. Preferably accordion-style. By checking one or multiple checkboxes, the editor can create a relation between different posts.

Comment: Imagine: a custom post type called "additional information". The edit screen features a metabox for (almost) every public post type (post, page, all public custom post types except for "additional information" itself). The posts metabox displays all posts with checkboxes, just like the pages metabox displays all pages and so on. By checking one or more of them, the "additional information"-post gets "attached" to posts/pages/etc. by adding a postmeta entry.